# Exporting a SharePoint list to Excel is exporting the entire list, not just the view I want

Tags: sharepoint-online, export-to-excel

Exporting from SharePoint Online list should only include the items in the view. However, when I export, I am getting all the items in the list. I tried various browsers. Anyone know a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try by applying filter in the edit view and the data return in view will be in exported file
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Sunil. The filtered view is exporting all items instead of just the filtered ones. I can always filter again in Excel, but I don't understand why it's not working the way it used to (only exporting what is shown in the view).

Comment: Can you share the item count and index details?

Comment: The filtered view is exporting correctly when I checked today. Possibly there was some sort of glitch last week that was since resolved. Can't think of any other reason. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: if it resolves your problem can mark as answer?